# Updating backbone collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a Restful service that returns a JSON array of objects. The service allows the user to specify max results and pagination of data. I map this service to a collection and set the max_result to 10 and page 1 by default. I want now to fetch data from next page and update/change the models in the collection how can I accomplish this.
Backbone Collection:

```
define(['backbone','models/Video'],function(Backbone,Video) {
return Rock = Backbone.Collection.extend ({
    model:Video,
    url:"/root/max_result/page"
});
});
```

Comment: Do you want the second page of items added to the collection, so the collection would end up with both pages? Or do you want the new page to replace the first page of items?

Comment: No I want only the new page of items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the url will look like `'/root/10/2'` for page 2?

```
define(['backbone','models/Video'],function(Backbone,Video) {
  return Videos = Backbone.Collection.extend ({
    model:Video,
    initialize: function(models, options){
        // get options.genre or use 'rock' as default
        this.genre = options && _.has(options, 'genre') ? options.genre : 'rock';
    },
    fetch: function(options){
       // make sure we have options object
       options = options ? _.clone(options) : {};

       // if no url in options, create url using options.page
       if(!_.has(options, 'url')){
         options.url = "/" + this.genre + "/10/" + options && _.has(options, 'page') ? options.page : 1;
       }

       return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.apply(this, [options]);
    }
  });
});

// fetch page 3
var rock = new Videos(null, {genre: 'rock'});
rock.on('reset', function(){
    // each time you fetch, this will be called.
});
rock.fetch({page:3});
```